# Angularjs directive attribute binding of left and top position after dragging

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a directive for jqueryui draggable, but I'm having some trouble getting the left and top position to bind to my scope after dragging. 
Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
myApp.directive('draggable', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.draggable({
            cursor: "move",
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                attrs.$set('xpos', ui.position.left);
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

Here's a fiddle of what I'm trying to do:  http://jsfiddle.net/psinke/TmQeL/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your directive:

```
scope: { xpos: '=', ypos: '=' },
```

The '=' syntax sets up two-way databinding between your isolate scope and the parent scope.  Any changes you make to these isolate scope properties in your directive also affect the parent scope too, and vice versa.

Then in the linking function:

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
  scope.xpos = ui.position.left;
  scope.ypos = ui.position.top;
  scope.$apply();
  scope.$apply();
}
```

There is a currently a bug in Angular where you have to call $apply() twice if you're setting an attribute on an isolate scope property bound with =.
See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1276

**Update:** @Peter noted in the comments that the above breaks moving the draggable via the input textboxes.  I was unable to get it to work with an isolate scope, so I just had the directive use the parent scope (i.e., the directive does not create a new scope).  I used attrs to modify the specified scope attribute in the stop() method.  This works with multiple draggables on the same page.

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
   scope[attrs.xpos] = ui.position.left;
   scope[attrs.ypos] = ui.position.top;
   scope.$apply();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/5Mzda/).

Comment: Hi Mark. Thanks for this. But by creating an isolated scope for the directive I can no longer use the ng-style and/or ng-show that I'm currently using on the div. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yep, that will do it. Thanks a lot! Didn't know you could do that from the directive.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this will not work when using a bit more complex data in the scope? I've created a jsfiddle that shows two different windows, one with a simple variable from the scope, and one that uses a json object in the scope. http://jsfiddle.net/psinke/TmQeL/17/

Comment: figured it out. scope[attrs.xpos] works fine if xpos equals "varx", but if xpos equals "vars.position.x" this doesn't work anymore because this gets evaluated as scope["vars.position.x"] while this should be scope["vars"].position.x. So what I've done is create an eval function like so: eval("scope." + attrs.xpos + ' = ui.position.left') and that did the trick. I'm usually not a big fan of using eval, but I don't see another solution at this point.

Comment: @Peter, you could also do `scope.$eval(attrs.xpos + '=' + ui.position.left);`

Comment: @Peter, now that I know more about Angular, the real solution here is to use `$parse` (not `$eval`) whenever a scope property is specified as an attribute to a directive that does not use an isolate scope: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/EnHSz/).  This works with "varx" and "vars.position.x".

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem faced by beginners.

Add the following code. it will work.

> ```
>  stop: function (event, ui) {
>       scope.divleft = ui.position.left;
>       scope.divtop = ui.position.top;
>       scope.$apply();
>   }
> ```

Reason:
Whenever change happens in the jquery world, it should be communicated to AngularJS world by calling $scope.$apply().

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Even though this will work in the example, I was looking for a more generic solution. The directive is used more then once on the final page, so what I would like to do is change the supplied attribute variables in the scope. I am able to get it working when i define an isolated scope for the directive, but then the ng-style and ng-show on the div do not work anymore. I was hoping there was some other way to do this.

Comment: @Xaraz can you update your jsfiddle with the problem you described?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. It now has two draggable divs. So what the directive should do is update the used attributes in the scope to reflect the new x and y position. http://jsfiddle.net/psinke/TmQeL/